# What is msbot clone services for in Enterprise Bot Template?

Tags: botframework, bots

I need to know what is msbot clone services for in a Bot Enterprise Template? what is the main goal of this command, if I configurate a LUIS application in Azure, I need this command to use my LUIS in my local bot? Is there a way to configurate LUIS manually in Bot Enterprise Template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*FYI: Enterprise Bot is being replaced by [Virtual Assistant](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BotBuilder.VirtualAssistantTemplate), which doesn't use `msbot`.*

`msbot` is used for a variety of different purposes, but I'm assuming you're referring to [the `msbot clone` command](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/blob/master/packages/MSBot/docs/export-clone.md#cloning-services). Basically, it's just a command that makes all of the necessary services/resources in Azure and then updates your `.bot`/`appsettings.json`/`.env` file, depending on which is applicable to your environment.

You can use your own LUIS, but Enterprise Bot creates a lot of LUIS apps for you that are used in the bot. To use your own, you'd just need to add your LUIS config in your `.bot`/`appsettings.json`/`.env` file and then ensure that it's called in the appropriate places in your code. Personally, if I were to do this, I'd just run the `msbot` command and then replace whatever it generates with my own LUIS config.